# Не получается добавить main class

Tags: java

Говорит "Не удалось найти главный класс", а добавить его не получается

```
public class Person {
    String name;

    public  Person(String personName)
    {
        name = personName;
    }

    public String greet(String yourName) 
    {
        return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главный класс должен содержать метод `main`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Главный класс - точка входа в программу, этот класс должен содержать публичный метод `main(String[] args)`, с выполнения которого и начнется работа программы

Класс, который вы приложили к вопросу, скорее класс-модель, который должен хранить данные о неких персонах или описывать действия с ними. Он не может быть точкой входа.
Вам требуется другой класс, главный (с методом `main`), где будут создаваться объекты класса `Person` , осуществлятся манипуляции этими объектами и прочая логика программы